# How to use @ifstar with arguments

Tags: primitives

I want to use `@ifstar` to define a command, whose non-star version stores a value in a variable and whose star version reads the value from the variable. I tried the following. It doesn't produce an error, but doesn't print the value either.

```
\def\sndname#1{\@ifstar\@sndname{\def\@sndname{#1}}}
\sndname{Hello U2}
\sndname*
```

I know that I can use this pattern, but is there a way to do it as a one-liner?

```
\def\foo{\@ifstar\@foo\@@foo}
\def\@foo#1{...}
\def\@@foo#1{...}
```

Comment: You are reading the star as argument. `\def\sndname{\@ifstar\@sndname{\def\@sndname}}` works.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\sndname{\@ifstar\@sndname{\def\@sndname}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Set it \sndname{Hello U2}and use it \sndname*.
\end{document}
```

The trick is, that not `\sndname` reads the argument but `\def` inside `\sndname`.

Answer (score 7):

You're abusing LaTeX syntax guidelines. The *-version of a command should generally have the same mandatory arguments as the standard version.

You can use an optional argument, instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sndname}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\tl_use:N \l_cocomore_sndname_tl}
    {\tl_set:Nn \l_cocomore_sndname_tl { #1 }}
 }
\tl_new:N \l_cocomore_sndname_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\sndname[Hello U2]
\sndname

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, a better approach would be to use different commands for setting the variable and for using it.

Answer (score 2):

An addition to @egreg's answer, which I agree has a better syntax, but without `xparse`. The commented version is a TeX style definition of the command, and the uncommented is a LaTeX style definition. In the LaTeX definition the optional argument can only take a default value, here set to `\empty`, which can then be checked in the code. It should work as long as it is not loaded with `\empty`. The dots around the commands when used are just to check that no extra spaces are added. (Actually, the LaTeX version can probably be seen as a one-liner, but it is more readable like this:-)

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%% TeX style definition
% \makeatletter
% \def\sndname{\@ifnextchar[\opt@sndname\@sndnamevar}
% \def\opt@sndname[#1]{\def\@sndnamevar{#1}}
% \makeatother

%%%% LaTeX style definition
\newcommand\sndname[1][\empty]{%
  \ifx#1\empty
    \sndnamevar
  \else
    \def\sndnamevar{#1}%
  \fi}

%%%% Load with nothing (just in case \sndname is used before loaded)
\sndname[]
%%%%
\begin{document}
Load: .\sndname[Name of snd].

Print: .\sndname.

\end{document}
```